# Communication with two different threads on same server

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

So I'm trying to create a multiplayer battleships game. At the moment I have a thread for each client but I was wondering, once I pair two clients up, would I place them in a new thread for a game? If so, would I store the client threads in the game thread or just the socket. The ObjectInput and Output streams are located inside the clientThreads and I am unable to read from them once the gameThread starts.

Server:

```
public static void startGame(String player1, String player2) {

    matchCount++;

    ClientThread c1 = connectedClients.get(player1);
    ClientThread c2 = connectedClients.get(player2);

    try {
        c1.serverOut.writeObject(protocol.createMessage("send-invite", "true", "Match Started."));
        c1.serverOut.flush();
        c2.serverOut.writeObject(protocol.createMessage("send-invite", "true", "Match Started."));
        c2.serverOut.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    lobbyList.remove(c1.player.getUserName());
    connectedClients.remove(c1.player.getUserName());
    c1.signedIn = false;
    c1.inGame = true;
    lobbyList.remove(c2.player.getUserName());
    connectedClients.remove(c2.player.getUserName());
    c2.signedIn = false;
    c2.inGame = true;

    sendUpdatedList();

    GameThread game = new GameThread(c1, c2);

    gameList.put(matchCount, game);
    gamePool.execute(game);
}
```

ClientThread:

```
public class ClientThread implements Runnable {
boolean signedIn = false;
boolean inGame = false;
private Object received;
ObjectInputStream serverIn;
ObjectOutputStream serverOut;
Player player;
Socket clientSocket;
private SimpleProtocol protocol;
private Database user;

/**
 * @param socket
 */
ClientThread(Socket socket) {
    clientSocket = socket;
    this.protocol = new SimpleProtocol();

    try {

        this.serverIn = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        this.serverOut = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));

        serverOut.writeObject(protocol.createMessage("send-message", "Welcome to the Server."));
        serverOut.flush();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


@Override
public void run() {
...
```

GameThread:

```
public class GameThread implements Runnable {

private ArrayList<String> inGameMessages = new ArrayList<>();
private ClientThread client1;
private ClientThread client2;
private Player player1 = null;
private Player player2 = null;
private SimpleProtocol protocol = new SimpleProtocol();

/**
 * @param client1
 * @param client2
 */
public GameThread(ClientThread client1, ClientThread client2) {
    this.client1 = client1;
    this.client2 = client2;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
       Object  received1 = client1.serverIn.readObject(); //This never seems to run

       Object received2 = client2.serverIn.readObject(); 
....
```

Comment: *"once I pair two clients up, would I place them in a new thread for a game?"* - I think that would be a valid assumption, because if you didn't what ever thread was doing the pairing would then become blocked while the "game" coordinate the information between the other two clients

Comment: But would I add the Client thread objects to the new game thread, or just the sockets from both clients. Or does it not make a difference? Because at the moment I use the client Thread objects as parameters for making a new game thread and my input and output streams seem to stop working.

Comment: I can't see how one `ClientThread`-s `serverOut` writing appears in another `ClientThread`-s `serverIn`-s `InputStream`. Can you show us how those threads are being connected?

Comment: Basically I have two Objects (received1 and received2) which read the output from clients 1 and 2 respectively. But the read methods in the game thread never seem to work and instead it tried to read in the client thread class instead.

Comment: @IshmaelA. I would add the threads